# Qgis PCA plugin not responding

Tags: qgis

I am trying to do principle component analysis, my file size is 1,5GB. It has been not responding past 30 mins,  but I decided not to close the program, is it running or I am just waiting for nothing?

Comment: 1.5 GB is a huge file, I wouldn't be surprised if it runs for a good few hours! If you access your **Task Manager** (right-click the bottom toolbar on the Desktop) and look for process `qgis-bin.exe`, if there's a high value in the _CPU_ column then it often means that it's processing data. You may just need to wait it out.